# Python 3 - Error handling to calculator

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, error-handling, calculator

I'm doing a simple calculator in Python 3 for training purposes.

This is where i'm at right now:

```
import math
number1 = int(input("Give the first number: "))
number2 = int(input("Give the second number: "))

while True:
     print("(1) +\n(2) -\n(3) *\n(4) /\n(5) sin(number1/number2)\n(6)  cos(number1/number2)\n(7)Swap numbers\n(8)quit")
     print("Selected numbers:",number1,number2)
     selection = int(input("Choose (1-8): "))
     if selection == 1:
         print("The answer is:", number1+number2)
     elif selection == 2:
         print("The answer is:", number1-number2)
     elif selection == 3:
         print("The answer is:", number1*number2)
     elif selection == 4:
         print("The answer is:", number1/number2)
     elif selection == 5:
         print("The answer is:", math.sin(number1/number2))
     elif selection == 6:
         print("The answer is:", math.cos(number1/number2))
     elif selection == 7:
         number1 = int(input("Give new first number: "))
         number2 = int(input("Give new second number: "))
     elif selection == 8:
         break
     else:
         print("Invalid selection.")
```

What i want to do now is to check the user input if it contains only numbers.
If the input contained characters the program would print "Invalid input" or so and then it would ask for the numbers again (While loop?).
Also in the selection i would like to check that the selection number is between 1 and 8, everything else would result in asking the numbers again.

What i've heard this i can do with `try: ... except (TypeError, ValueError)`. But i can't manage to get it work. Do i need to think of rewriting my code?

Comment: Please format your code so that it is legible.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check that the input only contains numbers it looks like you want [`isdecimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal) from the standard library, this checks to see if the string contains a valid decimal number.

Example usage:

```
>>> a = "123"
>>> a.isdecimal()
True
>>> b = "123foo"
>>> b.isdecimal()
False
```

Also I'd strongly consider using a dictionary to store the choices that stores functions that get called by those choices instead of the big if-else block you have here. I could say more but that's starting to get into code-review territory which would be more appropriate in a question over on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/